# SQL: How to check "if this record exists then that record must also exist" for given ID set

Tags: mysql, multiple-conditions

my database table (DWInfo) looks like this:

```
InstanceID | AttributeID
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 1
2          | 4
3          | 1
3          | 2
```

There are several instances and every instance has multiple attributes.
What I want to achieve is this: for a given set/rule of id's I want to get all InstanceID's which violate the condition, for example let the given ID's be 1 and 2, which means if there is an instance with AttributeID=1, Attribute=2 should also exist for it. In this case the result would be instance two, because this instance violates the condition.

I tried it with JOINS but this only seemed effective for 2 attributes and not more.

```
Select * from DWInfo dw1 INNER JOIN DWInfo dw2 ON dw1.InstanceID  = dw2.InstanceID  where dw1.AttributeID != dw2.AttributeID and dw1.AttributeID = 1 AND dw2.AttributeID != 2
```

Is it possible to solve this problem with a SQL query?

Comment: don't understand your question please put an example of the resulting query you want

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez OP states they wants the result 2 from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each `InstanceId` can have only one of each different `AttributeId`, i.e. a unique composite index `(InstanceId, AttributeId)`:

```
  SELECT InstanceID
    FROM DWInfo
   WHERE AttributeID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY InstanceID
  HAVING SUM(AttributeId = 1) = 1 
     AND COUNT(*) < 2  /* Or SUM(AttributeId = 2) = 0 */
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c65cd/3)

Note that if having AttributeId of 2 means that the instance requires an AttributeId of 1 also.. slightly different logic, this is neater:

```
  SELECT InstanceID
    FROM DWInfo
   WHERE AttributeID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY InstanceID
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select instanceid
from dwinfo
where attributeid in (1, 2)
group by instanceid
having count(*) = 2;
```

This guarantees that you have two matching rows for each instance.  If you can have duplicates, then use:

```
having count(distinct attributeid) = 2
```

EDIT:

For the conditional version (if 1 --> 2):

```
having max(attributeid = 2) > 0
```

That is, if it has 1 or 2, then it has to have 2, and everything is ok.

Comment: Technically the question hasn't indicated that having AttributeId of 2 but not 1 is a violation; just having an AttributeId  of 1 but not 2. Also the question was how to get the violations not the correct instances.

Comment: @Arth you're right. Having AttributeID 2 but not 1 is a violation.

I didn't remember the IN function, but as Arth said, I need the violations. But this is still very helpful. If there is no other possibility I first can query all data that contains the first attribute and then use your solution to get all instances which fulfill the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Where there exists Attribute 1 find the ones that don't have Attribute 2.

```
select InstanceID
from DWInfo
group by InstanceID
having
        count(case when AttributeID = 1 then 1 end) > 0
    and count(case when AttributeID = 2 then 1 end) = 0
```

This answer is basically the same as Arth's. You might find it beneficial to filter the Attributes in the `where` clause but it's not strictly necessary. I prefer the standard syntax using `case` expressions even though the shorthand would be handy if it were portable. I also prefer `count` over `sum` in these scenarios.

It's not clear whether you can have duplicates (probably not) and whether Attribute 2 can appear alone. You might have to tweak the numbers a bit but you should be able to follow the pattern.